# Can I pass a component to register into an Autofac module?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I have a module, this module has an Interface that the consuming application needs to implement.

I would like to pass that implementation back into my module so that the registration happens in the Module.load() method.

I would expect to pass in a type with a specific base type. (Which I'm not sure is possible either)

I hope this will give me a compile-time error if the module user forgets to register the interface component.

Comment: Could you share what you already tried ?

Comment: I actually didn't know where to start with this, I kept battling and found the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I was looking for eventually worked with generics, the bit of C# that I was not familiar with was the Where clause this allowed you to specify the parent.
And the TAppUSerQuery was a variable I could use in my Autofac config.

my class header looked like this

```
public class AuthConfigurationModule<TAppUserQuery> :Module
    where TAppUserQuery : IAppUserQuery
```

My Autofac load function looked like this.

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<TAppUserQuery>().As<IAppUserQuery>();
        builder.RegisterType<ResolveApplicationUser>().As<IResolveApplicationUser>();
        builder.RegisterType<AuthUserRepository>()
            .As<IAuthUserRepository>()
            .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), _connection));
    }
```